# Google Places Autocomplete API - threading

Tags: android, http, google-places-api

I have implemented autocomplete of Google Places using the API following this tutorial pretty strictly - https://developers.google.com/places/training/autocomplete-android. My question is, why is this working when no multi-threading work has been done - no asynchTasks or anything. Shouldn't the app be crashing, as there is an http request from the main thread?
Here'e the line that I would think the app would crash at -

```
conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The network call is performed inside the `Filter.performFiltering` method:

```
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    Filter filter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            if (constraint != null) {
                // Retrieve the autocomplete results.
                resultList = autocomplete(constraint.toString());

                // Assign the data to the FilterResults
                filterResults.values = resultList;
                filterResults.count = resultList.size();
            }
            return filterResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            else {
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        }};
    return filter;
}
```

As you can see from the documentation, the `Filter.performFiltering()` method is executed inside a worker thread:

> Invoked in a worker thread to filter the data according to the
>   constraint. Subclasses must implement this method to perform the
>   filtering operation. Results computed by the filtering operation must
>   be returned as a `Filter.FilterResults` that will then be published in
>   the UI thread through `publishResults(CharSequence,
>   android.widget.Filter.FilterResults)`.